# How to capture multi-line output for commands issued with PHP exec?

Tags: php, exec, command-line-interface

I am trying to execute system commands in PHP and capture the output of those commands where that output covers multiple lines.  I am using exec(), but it seems like it only returns a value for commands that generate output on a single line.

For example, if I run date at the command line I get:

```
 Wed May 15 15:07:32 EST 2013
```

As expected, if I run this command from PHP as an exec using this...

```
exec("date",  $exec_results);
```

...then the value of $exec_results becomes...

```
Array ( [0] => Wed May 15 15:07:32 EST 2013 )
```

However, when I run time from the command line I get this...

```
real 0m0.000s
user 0m0.000s
sys  0m0.000s
```

...but when I do it from PHP with this...

```
exec("time",  $exec_results);
```

... the value of $exec_results is empty:

```
Array( )
```

I don't actually need to run date or time in my application but these are just examples of how the single line vs. multi-line output on the command line seems to change what gets back to PHP.

The documents say:

> If the output argument is present, then the specified array will be filled with every line of output from the command.

So why is the $exec_results array not being filled with all the lines seen when the time command is run in the command line?

Notes - I have run the command line entries as the apache user to rule out privileges.

Answer (score 10):

This should work for you

```
ob_start();
passthru("ls -la");
$dat = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: Thanks - That worked for 'ls -la', but not for time, or for the multi-line output from the Dell OMSA program I am trying to capture.  Not sure what the difference is... I'll keep researching.  Thanks!

Comment: are you sure those commands are writing to stdout and not stderr

Comment: I checked there weren't errors using exec()'s third parameter, so that should mean the output comes as stdout, though to @Ph.T's perhaps the output is screen only.  I have found another solution by having a CRON job run the command and put the data in the file.  PHP will just lookup the file.

Answer (score 7):

So here's the full list:

- `system()` => Execute an external program and displays the output.
- `passthru()` => Same than system, but casts the output in binary "as is" from the shell to the PHP output (typically the HTTP response).
- `exec()` => Captures the output and only the last line of the output into a string.
- `shell_exec()` => Same than exec, but capturing full output, not only the last line.

So, my preference: Always use `shell_exec()` and then do with the full-string whatever you want.

### How to test

```
$ php -a
Interactive mode enabled

php > echo( shell_exec( "echo hello; echo bye" ) );
hello
bye
php >
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

Comment: This was more helpful in my opinion.  Switching from exec() to shell_exec() is all one probably needs to do.  Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I changed my post for the working solution:

Use the 'script' command of unix to get the result. 
you will surely have to remove "extra lines" of the temporary log file.

```
exec('script -c "time" /tmp/yourfile.txt');
$result = file('/tmp/yourfile.txt');
var_dump($result);
```

You should always put a full path to your temporary file, anywhere you put it

that's it !

Comment: Thanks for the idea - I tried shell_exec but unfortunately found it also returns nothing to PHP for commands where the CLI output is more than one line.  Still puzzled...

Comment: Be carefull, actually the problem with cron and write to file is exactly the same problem as PHP, if the command does not write to console it is not capturable by a redirector:    #time > file.txt will NOT put the result into the file either

Comment: Thanks Ph.T - You are right that doesn't work for time.  It did work for the command to the Dell OMSA application though (which is what I want to capture in PHP).  So in that example, what prints on screen can be moved to the file, but PHP still just gets an empty array.  My workaround works, but it's a shame we can't find out why PHP is able to get the text...

Comment: Hi Dan, I changed the post so it works even with the 'time' unix command, through the 'script' command. It uses a temporal file either. Enjoy